# 07 Escalade - Adjust pulley alignment?

Tags: pulley, serpentine-belt, escalade

2007 Escalade 6.2L, AWD, 140k miles

Is it possible to adjust the power steering pump pulley alignment (forward/back)? It's a few mm out of plane with the rest of the pulleys and tensioner, and the serpentine belt walks a rib off of the crankshaft pulley after driving a bit. Belt dressing (blech) keeps things working fine for awhile, but that's not a viable long-term solution, and shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: What work have you had done to mis-align the pulleys? has the pump been replaced and the new one does not match correctly? It is unlikely to have come like that from the manufacturer - but then, weirder things have been known (a brand new car had a 5 speed gearbox instead of what was listed in it's spec sheet as a 4 speed...)

Comment: @SolarMike no work done, but I've only had the car for a little over a year. I'm also confused as to how his happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after further investigation, I discovered that the tensioner pulley is also "too far back" by the same amount as the PS pulley.

In other words: the crank pulley has shifted forward.

The bolt holding the pulley on was only finger-tight. The IntarWeb buzz is that this happens a lot on Chevy small blocks. (L92 in my case.) Hopefully it's just a matter of getting a new bolt and finding someone with a torque wrench that can do 240 lb. ft. This is a torque-to-yield bolt; I'm surprised that it came loose.

Then again, it made it 140k miles, so...

Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can move the pump in/out but the pully can be moved using a special tool to remove and a not so special tool to install( bolt and nut and washers) to press pully in